# Differentiable and convex but not logarithmically convex function satisfying Gamma's functional equation

Tags: real-analysis

Regarding the Bohr-Mollerup theorem, is there a function $f$ that is smooth (or simply differentiable), convex but not logarithmically convex that satisfies the functional equation
$$f(x+1)= xf(x)$$
and also the equation $f(1)=1$?

If so could you please give me an example of one?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in Zur axiomatischen Charakterisierung der Gammafunktion by Hans-Heinrich Kairies: Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik Band 236: 1969, pp. 103-111. Below is a link to images from the Göttinger Digitalisierungszentrum.

http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0236&DMDID=DMDLOG_0011

Or better:
Convexity in the Theory of the Gamma Function by Hans-Heinrich Kairies; pp. 49-62 of General Inequalities I E. Beckenbach ed., Springer Basel AG 1978

Comment: The German article by Hans-Heinrich Kairies refers to [Mayer, A.E. *Konvexe Lösung der Funktionalgleichung $1/f(x+1) = xf(x)$*. **Acta Mathematica** (1939)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485888238) for the claim: "conditions $f(x) > 0$, $f(x) \in C^{\infty}$, $f(x)$ convex, $f(x+1) = x f(x)$ and $f(1) = 1$ are not sufficient for a unique characterization of $\Gamma(x)$."